# Must a solution of $x^2 + 4y^2 = p$ be unique

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime with $p = 4k + 1$. Has the equation 
$$
 x^2 + 4y^2 = p
$$
for $x,y \in \mathbb N$ at most one solution?

Comment: Do you know about Gaussian integers, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? Essentially, the uniqueness of the representation is equivalent to the Gaussian integers being a UFD.

Comment: I heard of them. Okay with the help of wikipedia I can see the arguments: we have $x^2 + 4y^2 = (x - 2iy)(x+2iy)$ and both $x-2iy$ and $x+2iy$ are primes in $\mathbb Z[i]$, which implies that this factorisation is unique (up to units), i.e. $x$ and $y$ are unique too, right?

Comment: The unit factor (= power of $i$) is used to make the imaginary part even, and $x$ positive. Conjugation is then used to make $y$ positive, too. Those two actions cover all of the dihedral symmetry present.

Comment: Right. Since the units in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are $\pm 1, \pm i$, a representation $p = a^2 + b^2$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ is unique up to sign ($(-a)^2 = a^2$ etc.) and order ($b^2 + a^2 = a^2 + b^2$). Requiring $a,b$ non-negative and $b$ even makes the representation unique.

Comment: Thank you for your help, would you mind writing an answer so I can check this question as answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x$ and $2y$ must be coprime. Now, suppose WLOG $x>2y$. Since $4y^2=(2y)^2$, by Euclid's formula for generating pythagorean triples we have $$(x^2-4y^2)^2+(4xy)^2=p^2,$$ hence $(x^2-4y^2,4xy,p)$ is a primitive triple, and as such arises from a unique pair of coprime numbers, namely $(x,2y)$.